# Need to match string in one list to string in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists, the first list `keywords` contains keywords `['aca','old']` and the second list `Tbl_names` contains table names from a database. I need to fetch the table names which match the keywords in the first list. The problem is that using the `in` operator in Python is giving me the wrong results if there is a `staging_vaca_2019` or `tapi_sold` table in the second list, as these two outputs should not be returned. If i use the '=' operator then a table with the name 'aca_2019' will not be returned which should be returned .

I am saving the matching table names in another list called `Tbl_keywords`.
The problem is that if I try to separate using delimiters, then I wont be able to append it like I am doing in the code below.

```
for a in keywords:
    for j in Tbl_names:
        if a in j:
            Tbl_keywords.append(j)
```

Comment: Why not use a dictionary/hashmap?

Comment: How would I use it?

Comment: Obviously 'old' is in 'sold', so you know the problem here, but for the solution, should it match tapi_old, or does the keyword need to be exact? You may have to split on '_' to get all the separate words. Also you should present a [mcve] You could have provided keywords = ['aca', 'old'] in the code so it could actually show the problem instead of just describing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information given, I'd just add `.split("_")` to your `j`.

It all depends on the format of your table names. If your table names are always separated by an underscore (like your example `'aca_2019'`), then you can split the table names on underscores into a new list. So, using the same example, you can use `'aca_2019'.split("_")`, giving you the following list: `['aca', '2019']`.

You can then check if `'aca'` is in this list. Even if there is no underscore, you will always receive a list by using `split()`. This makes sure you will not match `aca` to `vaca`, as would be the case when using `in` against a string (like in your working example).

```
for a in keywords:
    for j in Tbl_names:
        if a in j.split("_"):
            Tbl_keywords.append(j)
```

But if your table names are stored differently (we cannot know), then i'd start looking into regular expression (the `re` module in Python).

Comment: Tables are separated by '.' and '_'. Only these 2

Comment: In that case, at the end, I would add an `elif` statement:  `elif a in j.split("."):` with the exact same append afterwards.

Make sure it's an `elif` and not a normal `if`, because if your table name is exactly `'aca'` and you have a normal `if`, it would be appended twice as the split on `"_"` and `"."` without these characters gives the same result (`['aca']`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue to use the double loop like you have.

Change the if statement.

Old:

```
if a in j:
```

New:

```
if a == j:
```

Answer (score 0):

I provided both answers, in case you want exact matches only, or just whole words in the table name. You want keywords to be a set. You can iterate over just the table names (not both lists, that's O(n^2) and do O(1) set lookup, n times.

I used list comprehension syntax instead of a for loop. It's slightly more efficient, but not a big algorithmic problem like your double for loop. If you want, I can translate those to for loops, but I recommend getting used to them.

```
# keywords should be a set for faster lookup
keywords = {'aca', 'old', 'exact', 'partial'}

# Tbl_names will be a list (resultset)
table_names = ['staging_vaca_2019', 'tapi_sold', 'exact', 'find_partial_match']

# exact matches
exact_matches = [table for table in table_names if table in keywords]
print ('exact matches:', exact_matches)

# keywords that appear as whole words inside the table name
all_table_keywords = [word for table in table_names for word in table.split('_') if word in keywords]
print ('partial matches:', all_table_keywords)
```

> exact matches: ['exact']
>   partial matches: ['exact', 'partial']

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to iterate only through `Tbl_names`:

```py
result = [item for item in Tbl_names if item in keywords]
```